# How to use galleria to create slideshow of Images in a Node

Tags: nodes, javascript, media

Can http://drupal.org/project/views_galleria be used to create a slideshow of images in an image field on the node display page (i.e. /node/*)?

When I go to "Manage Display" for the content type, I do not see "..Galleria.." as one of the display options for the image field that can take multiple images?

I am able to use http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow but it is not as nice.

Any recommendations of other decent looking slideshow modules is also welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this solved alot of issues with having slideshows specific to a node's image field:

http://drupal.org/project/field_slideshow

you dont have to build any views.

Answer (score 1):

Quick solutions [eva](http://drupal.org/project/eva) module , with this you can set up a view of images with contextual filter (nid) , then attach it to the content type , then it will be available under manage display

Comment: I was able to do this (after i posted the question) with module: http://drupal.org/project/galleria

Comment: I'm happy for you , just for advise , eva module is great , try to learn more about because it's generic and you can solve lot of problem with

Comment: Thanks for the link. I did not know about this. Definitely looks promising, esp for the project I am working on - thanks.